# how to change fragment telegram channel username with python?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

not working framments tg channel username with telehton

not working framments tg channel username with python with  btelehton

`` `result = client(functions.channels.UpdateUsernameRequest( ``
`channel=current_username,`
`username=username`
`))`

`` ` ``